# How can I change cursor blinking speed in Xfce Terminal?

Tags: cursor, xfce4-terminal

I am using Xfce4 Terminal and enabled a blinking cursor.

How can I change the cursor blinking speed ?

Currently it seems to be set around 0,5s (based on my observation). I would like to speed it up a bit.

```
$ xfce4-terminal --version
xfce4-terminal 0.8.7.3 (Xfce 4.12)
```

Answer (score 4, accepted):

You can adjust the blinking speed of the cursor in `Settings > Keyboard`. In the `Behavior`-tab play around with the `Blink-delay`-slider. Reducing the blink-delay increases the blinking-speed.

[image]